# Matching a value from a csv file to a particular variable depending on the filename

Tags: python, pandas, csv, networkx

I have a column in a csv file that contains values I wish to match to a file in a python directory I have (I want to match by date). To do this I am attempting to match the date in the filename to the date in the csv.

The csv looks like this

```
Date        Count
17/08/2020    5
24/04/2020    1
18/02/2021    3
```

And my directory of files in python is like this:

```
'.../Graphs/graph_2020-08-04_2020-08-17.csv',
 '.../Graphs/graph_2020-04-11_2020-04-24.csv',
 '.../Graphs/graph_2021-02-05_2021-02-18.csv',
```

I wish to take the second date in that filename, and assign the Count value for that date from the csv. What I have is this

```
    # use glob to get all the csv files in the folder
path = r'...' # use your path

csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
dataframes = []
for csv_file in csv_files:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(csv_file))
```

and then get the second date in the filename

```
dates=csv_files[0][48:58]
```

and convert it into time format to make matching easier (?)

```
dates= pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

As I am creating networkx graphs, this Count value will be a label for each file in my directory, which I would add like this

```
labels = []
for graph in graphs:
    labels.append(Count)
```

However I am not sure how to match the Count for each date in the csv and assign it to the file in the directory. IS it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['17/08/2020', 5], ['24/04/2020', 1], ['18/02/2021', 3]], columns=['Date', 'Count'])
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

That looks like this.

```
        Date  Count
0 2020-08-17      5
1 2020-04-24      1
2 2021-02-18      3
```

What you can do is to select/filter the rows by a condition.

```
dates = ['2020-08-17', '24/04/2020']
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
df_filtered = df[df.Date.isin(dates)]
print(df_filtered)
```

Output:

```
        Date  Count
0 2020-08-17      5
1 2020-04-24      1
```

Then `df_f.Count.tolist()` will give you your Count values in the right order.

Comment: How will this allow me to do my task?

Comment: Read your csv using the `pd.read_csv` method. Then everything else stays the same as described in my answer.